# Logout in Facebook SDK Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my app I can log in to Facebook but I can't logout. When I click button which call logout function I get:

```
Object { authResponse: null, status: "unknown" }
```

Here is my code:

```
function login_to_fb() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email'
  });
}

function logout_from_fb() {

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I figured out it's because I refresh the page. Without it, scripts works fine but when I log-in and refresh the page then log-out is impossible. How can I save it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the result is cached. Try passing true as the second argument to clear the cache:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

Comment: That's weird. It worked only first time I used it. Then I login and try logout again but I ve received the same answer like before change. What is going on?

Comment: I figured out it is because I reload the page, meanwhile access token is lost.

Comment: How can I "save" this Access Token? Without refresh I can log-in and log-out but when I log-in and refresh the page then log-out is impossible.

Comment: @Roberto, when you reload the page, you can use something like localStorage to save whether the user was previously logged in, and then take a look at the recommended code in the Facebook Login section of this examples page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples)

Comment: Well it possible but what exactly I need to store in localStore? and how fb would know it is in localStore, can I do sth like 'response.authResponse.accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token_fb')' ?